# SSH Expect Password Issue with Login

Tags: ssh

Hi I've the following script that make an ssh login to my server.

```
  spawn ssh presnetwork@192.168.244.14
                              expect "*(yes/no)?"
                             send "yes"
                                expect  "password:"
                                  send  "pwd\n"
                              close
```

it works fine but it doesn't pass 'pwd' value to system, so script goes timeout and quit.
Any suggestions?

Comment: I would much rather suggest using ssh keys for use of ssh in scripts then having your password in that script file.

Comment: "it works fine but it doesn't pass 'pwd' value to system, so script goes timeout and quit." Sounds more like it doesn't work at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with "KbdInteractiveAuthentication" set to "no"
(`ssh -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication="no" presnetwork@192....`). SSH by default uses Keyboard Interactive Authentication, which is something `expect` might not understand.

I would strongly recommend that you use public key authentication instead (as already recommended by Flo). It is way easier to handle, and way more secure, and way more comfortable. If you are just looking for a way to login to a remote server without having to enter the password everytime, take a look at ssh-agent, which will store the password for you after you entered it *once* in your desktop session. If you really don't want to enter your password, use [pam_ssh](http://www.clasohm.com/blog/one-entry?entry_id=12085), where your desktop login password will be used.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the expect command is not yet installed. So, you to install it to acquire correct output.